# How to sort Google Sheets query result by column values (month names), numerically and within the query statement itself?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a formula which aggregates `IMPORTRANGE` data from external sheets and then combines the output of multiple queries, which works fairly well:

```
={IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C4, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C6, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C7, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C8, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C9, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C10, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C11, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C12, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C13, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C14, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C15, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C16, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C17, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C18, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C19, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C20, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C21, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C22, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C23, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C24, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C25, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C26, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C27, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C28, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C29, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C30, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C31, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""})},
"SELECT * WHERE Col8 IS NOT NULL AND Col1='PERSONAL' OR Col1='RESOURCER' OR Col1='NEW' ORDER BY Col12 desc", 0),{"","","","","","","","","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY({IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(MANAGERSHEET, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L200"), {"","","","","","","","","","","",""})},
"SELECT * WHERE Col8 IS NOT NULL AND Col1='PERSONAL' OR Col1='RESOURCER' ORDER BY Col12 desc", 0),{"","","","","","","","","","","",""})}
```

`Col3` in this query imports as a string value representing the month ("January", "February", "March", etc). I'm thinking also of explicitly selecting the Columns one by one (`SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, etc`) for more flexibility.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible *within the query statement* to convert (or interpret) this month value string so that I can sort by month numerically. i.e. January = 1, February = 2, etc.

I've tried looking through the official Google Query Language Reference (Version 0.7) and none of the scalar functions seem to be able to achieve what I'm trying to do or at least not in any of the ways I've tried. Googling the question hasn't found any pointers either, with most results relating to number to month string conversions or else suggesting some Google Sheets native functions that can't be used within the Query itself.

Is this possible within the Google Query Language in Google Sheets without having to resort to adding columns separately?

Can the month name be converted to a numerical value during the `SELECT` procedure or can it be interpreted as a number with the `ORDER` clause?

Answer (score 0):

if your months would be valid dates then you can do:

```
=QUERY(A1:A5, "order by month(A)", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

otherwise, you will need to convert it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:A5, MONTH(A1:A5&1)}, "select Col1 order by Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

---

to convert month name to a number:

```
=MONTH("August"&1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Your advice to convert it using the MONTH() function seems like it could work since the values are strings but the difficulty is I've got quite a few IMPORTRANGE values pulled together in an array. How would I go about converting just Col3 with the MONTH() function?

Comment: the most easier approach would be to add one helper column with arrayformula into your spreadsheet from which you do the importrange - `=ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(C4:C200&1))`. if that's not possible then you can assemble it in array which gets longer but works as well - `=IFERROR({IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!A4:B200"),MONTH(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!C4:C200")&1),IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!D4:L200")}, {"","","","","","","","","","","",""})` instead of one importrange. and wrap your wholoe formula into `ARRAYFORMULA()`. this this will convert the 3rd column from strings into numbers

Comment: I haven't been getting the output expected which wasn't helped by the IFERROR() functions so I've stripped it right back down to basics and have found that for this: `=MONTH(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!C4:C200")&1)` I'm getting a single value of "9" which makes sense but it's clearly not applying the MONTH() function to the imported range but to a single value. I've tried `=IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!C4:C200")` which works as expected and shows a list of month names as string values in a column, so the MONTH() function only parses and returns one row/value. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok this seems to work to get a column of numerical values for the month strings: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!C4:C200")&1))`. Now on to incorporating into the rest of the formula.

Comment: Turns out the format function isn't compatible with Google Sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0YnkXpXCD4rI/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2FYnkXpXCD4rI . How do I use the numerical value to sort but show the value as a string name for the month? i.e. "January" instead of '1' EDIT: I've acheieved this by applying a custom format from within Google Sheets which converts the number to the month name.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I managed to get it working although the MONTH() function didn't work as expected so I used DATEVALUE instead: `IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(IMPORTRANGE( 'C1'!C3, "PLACEMENTS!C4:C200")&1)), {""})`